# I want to invite an Azure AD B2C user to sign-in using the "Sign-in" User Flow but receive the error "We can't seem to find your account"

Tags: aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I want to invite a B2C guest user, have them accept the invitation, and then have them sign-in using a "Sign In" User Flow. When I do this I receive an error "We can't seem to find your account".

My B2C tenancy (e.g. testb2c) Identity Provider = "Local Account" and Configuration = "Email".

I have invited a new user to my B2C tenancy (e.g. "joe@gmail.com") by clicking "+ New Guest User" and selecting "Invite user". The user accepted the invitation. The user has been created in my B2C tenancy with User Type = "Guest", Source = "External Azure Active Directory", and the UPN (e.g. joe_gmail.com#EXT#@testb2c.onmicrosoft.com).

I have created a "Sign In" User Flow with defaults (Version = "Recommended", Identity Provider = "Local Accounts/Email signin", No MFA or Conditional Access).

When I initiate the "Sign In" User Flow and log in using the new users email and password, I receive the error message "We can't seem to find your account".

[Sign in error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSUkE.jpg)

This works fine if I select "Create Azure AD B2C User" when creating the user, or if I create the user via a "Sign Up" user flow. But I don't want an AD integrated account and I only want to create the user via an invitation.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thanks!
Kerry.

Answer (score 0):

That flow is only for admin users.

They are not local accounts hence why you can't sign in.

You can use a [magic link via invitation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite) to do this kind of use case.